# Can we get SOLR score value in response with document from SOLR?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to collect SOLR score value and use it further.

How we can get score value for product?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: The value comes as the `score` field in the response, but it is a calculated value and varies from query to query.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have score in the fl param.
for example append &fl=*,score in your solr url :
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/select?q=product_name:test&fl=*,score